# Alphabet Buckets

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> hoops(ArrayList<String> a) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(26);
    
    for (char x = 'a'; x <= 'z'; x++) {
        list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    
    for (int y = 0; y < a.size(); y++) {
        for (char x = 'a'; x <= 'z'; x++) {
            if (String.valueOf(x).equals(a.get(y).substring(0, 1))) {
                list.get(x).add(a.get(y));
            }
        }
    }
    
    return list;
}
```

This is code meant to "Write and test a method that takes a List words, which contains Strings of alphabetic characters, throws them into 26 "buckets", according to the first letter, and returns the ArrayList of buckets. Each bucket should be represented by an ArrayList. The first bucket should contain all the Strings from words that start with an 'a', in the same order as they appear in words; the second bucket should contain all the Strings that start with a 'b'; and so on. Your method should traverse the list words only once and leave it unchanged."

When I run the following code...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("cat", "dog", "person", "beetle", "insect"));
    ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 0, 1, 3));
    
    System.out.print(hoops(a).get('a'));
}
```

I get an error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 99, Size: 26
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:659)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
at marcoB.Reverse.hoops(Reverse.java:61)
at marcoB.Reverse.main(Reverse.java:13)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can't index your array on the letter 'c'. Index it on the offset of the letter 'c' in the alphabet, for example a=0 ,b=1, c=2. More generally `x - 'a'` (assumes lowercase). The exception shows you `Index: 99` because your test case is `cat` and the letter `c` is 99 decimal in the ASCII table.

Answer (score 0):

x is a char. Now the question you must be asking yourself where the `Index: 99` in the exception trace came from. With simple observation, you'll realize that the character 'c' has an [ASCII](http://sticksandstones.kstrom.com/appen.html) code 99.

This code

```
char x = 'c'
list.get(x).add(a.get(y));
```

is equivalent to

```
int x  = 99
list.get(x).add(a.get(y));
```

While I highly advise against indexing with chars since it results in smelly and unreadable code, a quick fix for your problem can come as follow:

```
for (int y = 0; y < a.size(); y++) {
    for (char x = 'a'; x <= 'z'; x++) {
        if (String.valueOf(x).equals(a.get(y).substring(0, 1))) {
            int index = x - 'a'; // 'c' - 'a' = 99 - 97 = 3
            list.get(index ).add(a.get(y));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I really appreciate it. If you have time, could you explain to me a way I could replace indexing chars with another method just for future reference?

Comment: @Marco Generally, index using integers. But with Java collections, I'd rather write for-each kind of loops. I am no expert in Java, I usually use streams when it comes to Java. Please accept the answer if it did solve your problem, for future readers.